# Como atualizar tabela automaticamente com Jquery/Ajax/PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Gostaria de saber como atualizar automaticamente a tabela com o load do Jquery pois já tentei colocar no arquivo principal e fica quebrando a tabela, dai aumentei o tempo do setInterval mais mesmo assim fica estranho, poderiam me ajudar?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#tabela').empty(); //Limpando a tabela
 $.ajax({
  type:'post',  //Definimos o método HTTP usado
  dataType: 'json', //Definimos o tipo de retorno
  url: 'consulta.php',//Definindo o arquivo onde serão buscados os dados
  success: function(dados){
   for(var i=0;dados.length>i;i++){
    //Adicionando registros retornados na tabela
    $('#tabela').append('<tr><td>'+dados[i].id+'</td><td>'+dados[i].nome+'</td><td>'+dados[i].quantidade+'</td></tr>');
   }
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/style.css"> -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="public/js/exibi.js"></script>

  <!-- O código abaixo mostra como estava fazendo a atualização -->

  <!-- <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var refreshAutomatico = setInterval(function(){
            $('#tabela').load("teste.php");
        }, 10000);
    });
  </script> -->
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1" width="500">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Nome</th>
              <th>Quantidade</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tabela">
        </tbody>
    </table>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uma alternativa é o seu PHP já retornar a tabela montada.

Comment: @KayoBruno pode até ser, mais como faria para ficar atualizando a cada 5 minutos

Comment: Nesse caso aconselho você a utilizar web socket.

Comment: Crie uma `<div id="resposta"></div>`  a cada 5 min execute um ajax que faça o select no banco e neste arquivo imprima a tabela, pegue a resposta do ajax e jogue com o `.append()`  dentro da div de resposta.

Comment: Crie uma função que carrega a tabela, e após feito o carregamento aguardar o tempo necessário para chamar novamente a função. Ex.: Dentro do `$(document).ready(function(){  fnCarregaTabela() });`. Dentro da sucess do ajax, coloque o `setTimeout(function(){ fnCarregaTabela()() }, 5000),` dentro do success, bem no final

Comment: Mas pq com o **load** não funcionou?

Comment: @LeAndrade da forma que escrevi ele funciona só que fica fazendo o mesmo evento que o form ao enviar que carrega a page toda queria algo mais que só carregasse os dados sem ter o aspecto de refresh